# How to map SOAP request with SOAP response using node-soap

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I use [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) to manage SOAP requests/responses on server side. I'm using [server.log](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#server-logging) function to log requests and responses and I need to somehow map them (connect) to know which request caused a certain response.

See the code sample:

```
function log(type, data) {
  let logId = '';

  if (type === 'received') {
    // On received I need to generate logId
    logId = generateLogId();
    console.log(logId, data);
  }

  if (type === 'replied') {
    // On replied I need to get the logId that was generated on the matching request
    logId = getLogId();
    console.log(logId, data);
  }
}
```

I've tried using node's [continuation-local-storage](https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage), but without much success.

> Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi. You're my only hope.

Comment: Show your code that I have used

Comment: Is it possible to log in MyFunction? You have access to both request and response there.
 MyService: {
          MyPort: {
              MyFunction

Comment: The log function is called once for the request and once for the response, so no, unfortunately.